# CentOS: can't resolve google.com

Tags: centos, networking, dns, resolv.conf

I've recently received an image of CentOS 7 and I'm having issues with resolving hosts. I'm currently on a company's VPN and all company's resources are available to me.

The problem is: nothing else is available. I've been trying to access websites like google.com and github.com and I'm getting errors like

```
unknown host google.com
```

How do I configure my resolver to fix this?

Contents of my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search vbox
nameserver 10.3.1.1
nameserver 10.3.1.2
nameserver 172.23.28.7
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
nameserver 172.23.28.8
```

Result of `host google.com 8.8.8.8`

```
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

google.com has address 216.58.208.142
google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4009:803::200e
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Result of `dig @8.8.8.8 google.com`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 57064
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             299     IN      A       216.58.208.174

;; Query time: 25 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Dec 02 11:13:43 GMT 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Comment: Can you reach any of the `nameserver`  10.3.1.1,10.3.1.2,172.23.28.7,172.23.28.8?
and if you are, are you sure that the one you can reach is working correct ?

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah Yes, I can ping them all by IP

Comment: Can you resolve internal company DNS names/sites?

Comment: did you try to use another DNS server like google one 8.8.8.8 ? in addition to your company DNSs

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes, those resolve fine

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah I've tried adding 8.8.8.8 as a nameserver to /etc/resolv.conf but seems like nothing changes, it still can't resolve google.com

Comment: can you ping 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah Yes, pinging 8.8.8.8 also works fine

Comment: ok try this `host google.com 8.8.8.8` or `dig @8.8.8.8 google.com`

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah I've added the outputs of both to my question

Comment: depending on the result of `host` and `dig` command you can use 8.8.8.8 as a DNS and there is nothing prevent you from that, when you added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` did you put it at the beginning of the file ?

Comment: Interesting, DNS connectivity....

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah Got it to work. You are right, I wasn't putting it in the beginning of the file. I did that now and it fixed the problem. But as far as I know /etc/resolv.conf gets overwritten by NetworkManager, is there a way to make this change stay there?

Answer (score 0):

So far I've just added line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` into my `/etc/resolv.conf` before all other nameserver lines and that fixed the issue. I'm still concerned about this change getting overwritten by NetworkManager though